# Getting an error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am working in react application and founded this stubborn thing.
This is my state in react to which i am working on

```
const [state, setState] = useState({
selectedParagraph: "Hello World!",
testInfo: [],
});
```

and now i am changing the state of testInfo by appending the selectedParagraph into it.

```
const selectedParagraphArray = state.selectedParagraph.split("");   // string into array                                                                        
const testInfoArray = selectedParagraphArray.map((selectedLetter) => {
  return {
    testLetter: selectedLetter,
    status: "notAttempted",
  };
});                                               //creating an array of object
                       
setState({ testInfo: testInfoArray });            //Changing state of testInfo
```

But when I am running it, then i am getting an error mentioning that
**TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be confusing `useState` with the class component's state.

Running `setState({ testInfo: testInfoArray });` sets the entire state to `{ testInfo: testInfoArray }`, removing `state.selectedParagraph` entirely, causing it to be `undefined`.

You'll want to use `useState` multiple times, like this:

```js
const [selectedParagraph, setSelectedParagraph] = useState("Hello World!");
const [testInfo, setTestInfo] = useState([]);
```

and edit like this:

```js
const selectedParagraphArray = selectedParagraph.split("");
const testInfoArray = selectedParagraphArray.map((selectedLetter) => {
  return {
    testLetter: selectedLetter,
    status: "notAttempted",
  };
});

setTestInfo(testInfoArray);
```

Comment: thanks! got what u r trying to explain. Solved this problem using your approach. Just in your solution instead of "testInfo(testInfoArray)"  it should be "setTestInfo(testInfoArray)"

Comment: :)   (fixed that)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this solution:

```js
String(null).replace('null',"");
```